# ビルド失敗：Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000

Tags: linux, node.js, npm

お世話になっています。
システム移管をしているNodeのアプリの実行時に下記のエラーが出て困っています。お力を貸していただけると助かります。

```
$ pm2-runtime start process.json
2019-02-06T00:45:50: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
2019-02-06T00:45:50: PM2 log: App [graphql:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-02-06T00:45:50: PM2 log: App [graphql:0] online
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1255:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1303:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1391:7)
    at /var/www/html/kotsu.fuzuki-crm.jp-backend/node_modules/graphql-yoga/src/index.ts:365:22
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at GraphQLServer.start (/var/www/html/kotsu.fuzuki-crm.jp-backend/node_modules/graphql-yoga/src/index.ts:363:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/kotsu.fuzuki-crm.jp-backend/src/index.js:51:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at loader (/var/www/html/kotsu.fuzuki-crm.jp-backend/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/var/www/html/kotsu.fuzuki-crm.jp-backend/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/kotsu.fuzuki-crm.jp-backend/src/index2.js:6:1)
2019-02-06T00:45:53: PM2 log: App [graphql:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
```

自分なりに調査して、アドレスが占有されている可能性を調査しました。

```
$ps aux | grep node
```

結果は4000ポートを占有しているものはなく、とっかかりが見つかっていません。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 参考: 英語版での類似質問 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075287/2322778

Comment: ポートの使用確認であれば、`ps`コマンドの代わりに`lsof -i :4000`の実行結果はどうなりますか？

Comment: `lsof -i :4000`の実行結果です。

Comment: `COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node\x20/ 948 yxxxxx   18u  IPv6  54055      0t0  TCP *:4000 (LISTEN)`

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます！！！解決しました！教えていただいたコマンドで見つかったPIDを`kill`することで解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

下記を実行。
`lsof -i :4000`
重複しているプロセスのIDがわかるので、そのPIDを`kill -9 PID`する